# Audio loop smooth start/end

Tags: jquery, audio, volume, smoothing

I have two buttons. When I click on the start, it starts the audio which plays in loop, and with the end button click it stops playing.
Now the audio starts and ends as it is, but **I would like to fade the audio in smoothly and also stop smoothly and not suddenly**. I read a lot of solution but non of them uses the same embed method like me and no idea how to integrate them.

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
    audioElement.loop=true;
    audioElement.volume=0;
    audioElement.addEventListener('ended', function() {
        this.currentTime = 0;
        this.play();
    }, false);
    audioElement.addEventListener('ended', function() {
        this.pause();
    }, true);

    $('.button-start').click(function(){
        audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'media/music.mp3');
        audioElement.animate({volume: 1}, 1000);
        audioElement.play();
    });
    $('.button-end').click(function(){
        audioElement.animate({volume: 0}, 1000);
        audioElement.pause();
        audioElement.currentTime = 0;
    });

});
```

I added `audioElement.volume=0` and on start click function `audioElement.animate({volume: 1}, 1000);`, and volume:0 on stop click function, but in this case the audio does not even start.

If someone knows the solution, please try to give me a clear answer because I am coding my personal websites by hobby, I am not professional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to make it with a loop using setInterval function.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var audioElement      = document.createElement('audio');
  audioElement.id       = 'audio-player';
  audioElement.controls = 'controls';
  audioElement.loop     = true;
  audioElement.type     = 'audio/mpeg';
  audioElement.src      = 'https://upnow-prod.ff45e40d1a1c8f7e7de4e976d0c9e555.r2.cloudflarestorage.com/d1ssYtCPdBd5hm6PO3SfNKbf51I2/80b1f91d-045f-4a2d-8dbd-34ebd2bf65f9?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=cdd12e35bbd220303957dc5603a4cc8e%2F20231005%2Fauto%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20231005T150523Z&X-Amz-Expires=43200&X-Amz-Signature=f6196f97ceed3262d53b4c94876f7947bca5d9dbbe724de5d593a900cbd6ad47&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3D%22BF3%20-%20Prgressive.mp3%22';
  document.getElementById('song').appendChild(audioElement);

  audioElement.addEventListener('ended', function() {
      this.currentTime = 0;
      this.play();
  }, false);
  audioElement.addEventListener('ended', function() {
      this.pause();
  }, true);

  $('.button-start').click(function(){
      audioElement.play();
      fadeInAudio(audioElement, 1000);
  });
  $('.button-stop').click(function(){
      fadeOutAudio(audioElement, 1000);
  });
});

function fadeInAudio(audio, fadeTime){ 
  audio.volume = 0; // set volume to the minimum 
  var steps = 500;
  var stepTime = fadeTime/steps;
  var audioIncrement = parseFloat(audio.volume + ("0.00" + steps));

  var timer = setInterval(function(){
    audio.volume += audioIncrement;
    console.clear();
    console.log(audio.volume);

    if (audio.volume >= 0.99){ //if its already audible stop the loop
       console.clear();
       console.log("1");
       audio.volume = 1;
       clearInterval(timer);
    }
  }, stepTime);
}

function fadeOutAudio(audio, fadeTime){ 
  audio.volume = 1; // set volume to the maximum 
  var steps = 150;
  var stepTime = fadeTime/steps;
  var audioDecrement = audio.volume / steps;

  var timer = setInterval(function(){
    audio.volume -= audioDecrement;
    console.clear();
    console.log(audio.volume);

    if (audio.volume <= 0.03){ //if its already inaudible stop the loop
       console.clear();
       console.log("0");
       audio.volume = 0;
       audio.pause(); 
       clearInterval(timer);
    }
  }, stepTime);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="song"></div>

<button class="button-start">Start</button>
<button class="button-stop">Stop</button>
```

Comment: I will try it tomorrow bcs it is late here... you must know that I have 6 start buttons which make diff. animations in their sections, and one stop button which takes back to the home scene. In each section scene there is a different sound, so I must integrate the sound sources in each button click function. Is it possible to put this code in the button click function? : `audioElement.src = 'https://...'`

Comment: If i answered your initial question, you can validate my answer and make a new one if you stuck in your development

Comment: I did not ask a new thing, I just asked something which is concerning your code above, so, there is no reason to make a new post. Well,I did not use these codes: 
`audioElement.id       = 'audio-player';
  audioElement.controls = 'controls';
  audioElement.type     = 'audio/mpeg';
  audioElement.src      = 'https:/...';
  document.getElementById('song').appendChild(audioElement);`,
also I let the source in the click function like this: 
`audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'media/music1.mp3');`
and it works now. I accepted your answer because it helped me, and thanks a lot !

Comment: I dont make your code, i just did what u needed to continue. Glad to see that it works. Good luck :)